# v-cards start at the top instead of vertical centering (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Below an image with my current result. So I want that these v-cards begin at the top

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqQc3.png

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <v-container grid-list-md >
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="i in 10" :key="`1${i}`" xs2>
          <v-card dark color="accent">
            <v-img :aspect-ratio="16/9" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material.jpg"></v-img>
            <v-card-text class="pa-0 pt-4 px-2 white--text">Jazz / Dub / Soul </v-card-text>
            <v-card-text class="pa-0 pb-2 px-2">By Lucas </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://codeply.com/p/nIJS2hWREZ  Please post all of the relevant code to recreate the issue. Is this template wrapped in another container?

Comment: Oh my.. I checked my general home layout and the <router-view/> was inside a container with a "fill-height" class. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted "fill-height" class from container at the general